# Enclosing div is higher than containing button

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to do a simple notification overlay. You can see my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/0uaqsz57/

relevant code is this:

```
<div class="close">
    <button class="btn action-link">close</button>
</div>
```

and

```
 .close {
        text-align: right;
        button {
            line-height: 1em;
            height: 1em;
        }
  }
```

Notice the button on the right side (nevermind the bad styling..). It has a height of 13px, according to chrome dev-tools. The enclosing div (.close), however has a height of 18px, but no (css-)padding.

in firefox, the button has a height of 13.33 px and the div a height of 21px

in internet explorer the height of the button is 5.33px and the enclosing div a height of 18.4px

So my Question is:
1. Why is this? Does the standard allow this behaviour and if so, why? I couldn't find specific information on this.
2. How to avoid this.

Comment: try taking the declaration out of the close dec. ie `.close {
        text-align: right;}.close button {
            line-height: 1em;
            height: 1em;
        }`

Comment: Css do not have nested elements. It's not LESS/SASS

Comment: Why not simple change the height of the button?

Comment: Have you tried floating the elements? The `line-height` could be the cause, as well as the `vertical-align`, which could make the button push... Try `float: left;` or `vertical-align: bottom;` and see if that works.

Comment: i use less, that is why i have the nested elements. jsfiddle apperenly does not have less, but scss seemed to work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting

```
height : 100%;
```

would be a robust option, as this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/0uaqsz57/2/) shows.

This is because your button can then happily scale depending on screen size.

```
 .close {
            text-align: right;
            button {
                line-height: 1em;
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
```

It means your 'button' will fill its parent container (in this case that's your `close div`).

Comment: note: if someone googles this: i had to set line-height of the close-container to 0, to make this or the other solution work for my final css. I'm not sure what triggers this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
height: 1em;
```

to:

```
height: auto;
```

I think this fixes your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/0uaqsz57/1/

Comment: this works, thanks :). Also found out, you can set the line-height of the parent to 0 and it fixes the issue as well.